# Is the vocative comma a recent thing?

Tags: punctuation, commas, history, vocatives

It's usually considered necessary in the modern day, but I find the further back you go, the less frowned on its absence seems to be. I seem to remember a few vocative sentences in The Hobbit without them, for instance, though I can't recall them at the moment.

Comment: The modern trend is to scale back on punctuation marks *in general* (dispense with unnecessary commas, "reduce" periods to commas, etc.) unless they're essential to avoid ambiguity. So I'd have expected the *opposite* to be the case. The "vocative comma" isn't really necessary in something like *Come here John* because John can *only* be the addressee. There's not likely to be any ambiguity in the *spoken* version of, say, *I know John*, but in the written form the presence / absence of a comma has always been (and remains) essential to disambiguate speaking ***to*** or ***about*** John.

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you're talking about?  They don't have to be from the Hobbit. I'll admit my ignorance of what is a vocative comma.  And, that way, perhaps people of my ilk will learn from your question, too!

Comment: https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/vocative_case_commas.htm - For whatever reason, I'd never heard this term. Damned American public schools!!!

Comment: I'd say that leaving the commas out the examples given in  [GrammarMonster](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/commas_with_vocative_case.htm) (as @David points out) would be unusual to ill-advised. The vocative stands as a parenthetical, and parentheticals are rarely not set off by commas at least. A dash or ellipsis seems sometimes quite acceptable and even preferable. You **need** to give examples (and references). // In a letter, etc, after 'Dear John', I think the comma is nowadays seen as unnecessary (and that means 'fulfils no useful role') (implication: perhaps best dropped).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree about the function of the comma in Dear John. But, doesn't one run the risk of seeming uneducated by dropping it?  It's been so engrained into my expectations, it's absence would bother me.

Comment: @DavidM I still usually follow the initial vocative comma with a line break and capitalisation of the first word of the body of the message (even in emails). I've found that layout odd from childhood but been using it dutifully for sixty-odd years and it's too late to stop now!

Comment: It would look out of place in this type of letter [[CAB](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/Documents/Advice%20factsheets/Unclassified/how-to-write-a-letter.pdf)]. Many sites still recommend (or mandate) the comma after << Dear Mr Smith >>, and some demand a colon in business letters, but [the Plain English Campaign](http://www.plainenglish.co.uk/writing-letters.html) mandates no comma. Commenters at [WordReference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/dear-mr-smith-comma-after-greeting-in-business-email.3322376/) come to the inevitable conclusion that there are no fixed rules....

Comment: I probably include a comma when writing to people I think might be bothered by my not using one, and go with the Plain English recommendation when I think I should be able to pull rank.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ah, the politics of letter writing punctuation . . .

Answer (score 2):

It looks like we’ve always had it. Look at Luke 18:13 in the Halgan Gospel (reprinted [1842](https://books.google.com/books?id=mA1kAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA162&lpg=PA162&dq=God,%20milde%20beo%20%C3%BEu%20me%20synfullum.&source=bl&ots=5mKh2SfAmR&sig=ACfU3U30-ZH_5cbbob8GCjkWjCvEBvRL1g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjCrIemvJTlAhVmRN8KHUMXD2wQ6AEwAXoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=God%2C%20milde%20beo%20%C3%BEu%20me%20synfullum.&f=false)) for example and note the comma after *God*:

> God, beo þú milde me synfullum.

([NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2018%3A13&version=NIV): God, have mercy on me, a sinner.)

I’m not sure when exactly this was written, but it’s Old English.

Comment: No; it's an 1842 revision, and punctuation has been chosen 'in line with the AV'. Which is a mystery, as the AV doesn't have the comma after 'God".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth well the comma is also present in a very similar quote in the OED for Theodulf of Orleans’ *Capitula* (can’t even find this online though)

Comment: Punctuation was rare or non-existant in Old English writing. It's highly likely this comma was added by a more modern editor and is not original.

Comment: The preface indicates that the punctuation is "comfortable to that of the authorized English version".