# When please is at the end of the request, but before a name, should there be a comma before and after the word 'please'?

Tags: punctuation, commas

I have found similar questions but couldn't find an answer to fit mine, so I am sorry if I have asked a question which has already been asked.

This is an example of the sentence:

"Sit down please John!"

Should it be "Sit down, please, John!" or "Sit down please, John!" or "Sit down, please John!"?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the vocative comma a recent thing?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/515194/is-the-vocative-comma-a-recent-thing)

Comment: I would prefer the first version, and definitely not the third.

Comment: It's certainly very plausible in speech. Should the best way to show it in writing (a) seek to adhere to a hard-to-find 'rule' drawn up by someone perhaps interested more in the rules per se than in how useful people would find them, or (b) seek to use commas in such a way as may most faithfully represent actual speech (but may be subjective and liable to misconstrual)? I can picture a no-pause << Sit down please John. >> but might chicken out with the probably less contentious << Sit down please, John. >> There _might_ be a hint of a pause, and _please John_ **may** be slightly garden-pathy.

Answer (score -1):

[Eats shoots and leaves....](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Eats-Shoots-Leaves-Lynne-Truss/dp/0007329067)  Is this a hungry gunman or a description of a panda bear?  It depends where you put the comma:

Eats, shoots and leaves - definitely a hungry assassin.

Eats shoots, and leaves - a description applicable to a panda bear in a zoo in Oxford (See [Oxford comma](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/what-is-the-oxford-comma-and-why-do-people-care-so-much-about-it/)).

Eats shoots and leaves - applicable to a less well educated panda bear that has never been to Oxford.

With regard to your question:

- "Sit down, please, John!"  - No - overly cluttered and difficult to read.
- "Sit down please, John!"  - probably a general comment to the room, with a forceful direct reference to John (*Who is being especially disruptive...*),from someone with some authority over John.
- "Sit down, please John!" - probably a general statement to the room, but from someone with less authority over John (Pleading for him to comply).